# Discontinuous clock for ISERDESE2

Tags: fpga

I want to use an ISERDESE2 to deserialize a bitstream from an ADC, but the clock of the ADC that samples the bits is discontinuous, it remains at '0' between two words sent.
Is this a problem if a try to use this clock as the CLK entry of the ISERDESE2?

Comment: Does the clock go though a PLL before driving your logic?  If so, then you have a problem.  If not, it might work.

Comment: In page 31 of this document [link](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm98640qml-sp.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-sf-df-ds-null-wwe) are the figures of the outputs of the ADC. I am not sure i will need the clock to go through a PLL as i allready have i frame clock and and a clock with its transition aligned with the center of the data eye.

Comment: If you already have a continuous data-aligned frame clock, I would just ignore the TXCLK and use an 8X version of your aligned frame clock to clock the received data as if was 8 bits of data.  Just ignore the unused bit.

Comment: The problem is that my frame clock is not constant, for the first word it will stay at '1' for 4 txclk periods for the second word it will stay at '1' for 3 txclk periods etc.. it will go on alternating like that. To use a 8x version i need a pll or a mmcm right?

Comment: Yes, to generate the 8X clock you would need a PLL or MMCM.  I was assuming that you are generating the INCLK to the ADC and that you can thus generate the equivalent of the TXCLK without the missing clock.  Note that the ADC looks like it can generate test patterns so that you can run a calibration to use the input delay to optimally align the data to the locally generated clock.

Comment: Yes in fact i can use the output INCLK and with an MMCM generate the 8X clock. But i don't understand how can i delay this new clock before entering in the iserdese2. I understood that the clk of the serdes can only come from either a mmcm or either and idelaye2 component but not from a combination of both an mmcm and an idelaye2

Comment: The input delay would not be used on the clock, only on the data.  You would feed the undelayed clock from the MMCM/PLL to the ISERDES2, and then adjust the phase of the data with respect to this clock using the input delay so that the data is center aligned on the rising edge of the 8X clock.  You can determine the best point by sweeping the delay and looking for the point at which it changes due to crossing and edge, and then adjust the delay to be half way between two edges.

Comment: Okay thank you this is helpful, so CLK and CLKDIV must be phase aligned and with transitions aligned with the center of the data eye? I have been reading this xapp https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp524-serial-lvds-adc-interface.pdf and i don't understand why the IDELAYE2 component is used as the bit clock (DCLK) out of the ADC is allready 90° phase shifted with the data.

Comment: Yes, CLK and CLKDIV must be phase aligned and also aligned to clock data in the middle of the valid range.  There are two ways of aligning things, by delaying the data or delaying the clock.  It looks like they use the IDELAY2 to delay the input clock so that they only have to tune one delay to shift the relative clock/data phase in the ISERDES2.  The other way you can have the same effect is to leave the input clock undelayed and shift all the data input delays.  It is slightly more resource efficient to just shift the input clock, since then you only have to control one delay.

Comment: But i don't understand why they delay the CLK as its transition are allready aligned with the center of the data eye?

Comment: It is aligned EXTERNALLY, but after all of the delays inside the FPGA and at the data inputs, it is likely no longer aligned.

Comment: Okay this makes sense, then i shall use the IDELAYE2 to delay the data and align it correctly with the undelayed mmcm generated clock. can the input CE1 (the clock enable of the ISERDESE2) remain at '1' all the time? or should i deassert it when the 7 bits of the word have been sampled and reassert right before the moment that the first bit of the second word is about to be sampled?

Comment: I would just leave it asserted and ignore the extra bit.

Comment: I just checked the diagram timings for INCLK and i need to delay of a value of tDOD+tQSR = 7070 ps (when INCLK = 40 MHz) Page 16 and Page 31 of  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm98640qml-sp.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-sf-df-ds-null-wwe , but the maximum delay for an IDELAYE2 componenent is 32 taps of 78 ps = 2496 ps. I assume i need to find a new strategy and use TXCLK and try to delay the signal TXFRM since the delay required to put TXCLK and TXFRM iin the same phase is way smaller. Does my reasonning make sense?

Comment: You can use dynamic phase shift in the MMCM that is generating your clock to incrementally delay a selected clock through an entire clock cycle.  Look at page 75 in https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug472_7Series_Clocking.pdf .  There is an example in https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp888_7Series_DynamicRecon.pdf .  If you are not using 7 series, there is similar functionality in other Xilinx families.

Comment: Okay thank you i am using a 7 series FPGA